# What is encrypted in Android operating system?

Tags: android, encryption

When the Android OS encryption is activated, I read that only /data (user data) is encrypted and not all the storage. Is this correct?
Can we encrypt all the storage if it's the case?
pictures are in \DCIM and we can have many folders in \

EDIT
If I take the Android folders structure:

```
┌─────────────┬───────────────────────────┐  
| Partition   | Explanation               |  
├─────────────┼───────────────────────────┤  
| /boot       | kernel & Co.              |  
| /cache      | app cache                 |  
| /data       | user data partition¹      |  
| /data/data  | app data¹                 |  
| /dev        | devices²                  |  
| /mnt/asec   | encrypted apps (App2SD)   |  
| /mnt/emmc   | internal sdcard³          |  
| /mnt/sdcard | external sdcard³          |  
| /proc       | process information²      |  
| /recovery   | used in recovery mode     |  
| /system     | system ROM (read-only)    |  
└─────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

What is encrypted when Android encryption is activated ?

Comment: Under security there is an option called encrypt phone. As for encrypting external cards, you can use third party apps. By all the storage, I think you mean both internal and external.

Comment: The system partition is usually read-only, therefore it can not be encrypted. Only the user data partition (usually containing the "sd-card" directory) can be encrypted.